# Fluid Layout - Space At Bottom When Using Margin-Top Percent

Tags: html, css, fluid-layout, spacing

So I'm trying to make a website using only percentages, however on my main content, I use a margin-top: 10%, but it makes spacing at the bottom and creates a scroll bar.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/6qKns.png
If you look at the image, you'll notice that even though the main content isn't expanding below the page, however it still creates space underneath (look at the scroll bar).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title></title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="main"></div>
    </body>
</html>


* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

html {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background: pink;
    position: relative;
}

.main {
    margin-top:10%;
    height: 600px;
    width: 960px;
    background: blue;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply remove the `height: 100%` style which you've assigned to the `body` inside your CSS. This is how it should be:

```
body {
    height: auto;
    width: 100%;
    background: pink;
    position: relative;
}
```